# Count number of operators in an expression - Cannot infer instance

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm working on a function that can count the number of operators used in an expression. My code is as follows:

```
data Expr = Lit Int |
    Expr :+: Expr |
    Expr :-: Expr

size :: Expr -> Int
size (Lit n)      = 0
size (e1 :+: e2)  = 1 + (size e1) + (size e2)
size (e1 :-: e2)  = 1 + (size e1) + (size e2)
```

But when I try to execute this code using Hugs98 i get the following error:

```
Main> size 2+3
ERROR - Cannot infer instance
*** Instance   : Num Expr
*** Expression : size 2 + 3
```

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? I'm really out of idea's myself.

Comment: +1 from me for not having an SO account and asking such a nicely formatted, phrased and tagged question.

Comment: You are missing parentheses around 2+3. Additionally, You have to add an instance of Num to your Expr type.

Comment: Just for fun: http://ideone.com/WsAk5

Comment: Additional fun (generics): http://ideone.com/mw762

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`2+3` is not a valid expression. With your types, primtive values are created using the `Lit` data constructor, and the valid operators are `:+:` and `:-:`. So what you really need is `Lit 2 :+: Lit 3`. So try

```
size (Lit 2 :+: Lit 3)
```

Comment: I see, thanks for that suggestion. I was under the impression that ':' would serve as an infix constructor. I really don't want anyone to make my homework for me but what would it take to make the function size take (2+3) as the parameter. Is my definition of Expr wrong or the function size itself?

Comment: @user967306: Nothing's wrong about those, `(2 + 3)` simply isn't an `Expr`, it's an integer (well, actually `Num a => a`). If you want to construct an `Expr` tree, you have to explicitly use those constructors (save clever tricks like making `Expr` an instance of `Num` and defining `fromInteger = Lit` and `(+) = (:+:)`, which are likely not intended to do and which may be bad for clarity in any case - but see Ramon's comment for how it's done).

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a Num instance:

```
instance Num Expr where
  (+) = (:+:)
  (-) = (:-:)
  negate = (0 -)
  fromInteger = Lit . fromInteger
  (*) = error "not implemented"
  abs = error "not implemented"
  signum = error "not implemented"
```

Once that is in place, `size (2+3)` will work (note the parenthesis).